# How to count consecutive grouping of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count consecutive groupings of dates in a table. I am almost there with using the query below. But there is a problem when the month changes. Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    UserId nvarchar(128),
    DateCreated Date,
    DOfYear int
)
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-19');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-24');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-28');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-29');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-02');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-03');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-07');
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-19');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        DateCreated, 
        StartDate = Dateadd(day,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated), DateCreated)
    FROM @Temp
)
SELECT 
    [LastDate] = MAX(DateCreated),
    TotalDays = COUNT(1)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StartDate
Order By StartDate desc
```

Here are the results:

```
LastDate    TotalDays
2016-02-19  1
2016-02-07  1
2016-02-03  3
2016-01-29  2
2016-01-24  1
2016-01-19  1
```

This query almost works except, as you can see, it on 2016-02-03, it should have included January 29, 28 which would have resulted in 5 instead of 3.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is an SQL Fiddle Example of the above code: [SQL Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f151e/2)

Comment: Err...  What's actually wrong here?  The next day after January 29 is January 30 (and then January 31), not Feb 1...

Comment: Actually, using -ROW_NUMBER like this probably won't give you what you want anyway.. it's just accidentally working here.

Comment: Wow, definitely stay up way too late trying to work through this.  Thanks for pointing out my stupidity :).  I had a February calendar up and i'm working on January dates. Thanks again.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve the query?

Comment: Is DateCreated unique in your actual data?

Comment: It is, no duplicate days here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works fine as long as `DateCreated` is unique (keeping in mind that January 29th is not followed by February 1st ;)

If DateCreated can repeat, you should probably do something like:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        DateCreated, 
        StartDate = Dateadd(day,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated), DateCreated)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DateCreated FROM @temp) t1
)
SELECT 
 [LastDate] = MAX(DateCreated),
    TotalDays = COUNT(1)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StartDate
Order By StartDate desc
```

That will ensure you don't get strange results if there are **two or more** entries for the same day.

Comment: Thanks Dan, appreciate your help and thank for the tip on duplicate dates.